# Django - Cannot resolve keyword 'total' into field

Tags: python, django

Am having a model called Cart which contains the following fields

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def total(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

I wish to get the total amount per item in django views.

Here is the cart views

```
def cart(request):    # Client View
    request_user = request.user

    item = Cart.objects.filter(client=request_user, ordered=False).values('total')
    print "item ", item
```

If i print item, i get
Cannot resolve keyword 'total' into field. Choices are: client, client_id, created_on, description, docfile, id, order_id, ordered, price, quantity

But if i print item when .value('price'), i get result.

Is there a way to get value of total amount

Comment: since i have a function total inside the class, can't i still assess it in the class modell

Comment: it should be a column.

Comment: I don't know why you want to use `values` here. You can access the `total` method via the instances themselves.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Roseman, figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this? ie, access the `total` method through `Cart` instance.

```
[i.total() for i in Cart.objects.filter(client=request_user, ordered=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create total function which will take price of each object you filter on the basis of client OR you can right query as follows:

```
total = 0

    for i in Cart.objects.filter(client=request_user, ordered=False).all():
        #print i.price
        total = total+i.price
```

You can't write `values('total')`, as you don't have any field in your card model as total.